# Matlab: reshape a vector by permuting?

Tags: matlab, permutation

I have the following vector `u`:

```
u=[a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4,c1,c2,c3,c4];
```

I want to permute the elements of of `u` to make the following vector, `uNew`:

```
uNew=[a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4,c4];
```

I can think of no way of doing this other than with a for loop:

```
uNew=[];
for i=1:4
    uNew=[uNew,u(i:4:end)];
end
```

But I'm hoping that a built-in function exits? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know before hand how many elements separate each vector?  For example, do you know that `a`, `b` and `c` are all the same size?  In addition, is there a possibility that there are more vectors?... could there be a `d`? `e`?

Comment: No there can't be d, e, etc. so I know everything about the vector. ai, bi and ci are scalars I used to make the concept clearer in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape it to a matrix which, read column by column, contains the order you want:

```
n=3 % number of categories (a,b,c)
u2=reshape(u,[],n).'
```

then convert it back to a vector:

```
u2=u2(:);
```

Comment: Was seriously just about to put this.

Comment: @rayryeng: Is there any alternative? ;)

Comment: ... not that I can think of currently!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Daniel's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32235034/2586922). But just to provide an alternative:

```
m = 4; %// size of each initial "block"
[~, ind] = sort(mod(0:numel(u)-1,m)+1);
uNew = u(ind);
```

Note that this works because, as per [`sort`'s documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html),

> The ordering of the elements in B (*output*) preserves the order of any equal elements in A (*input*)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
N = 4;
uNew = u(mod(0:numel(u)-1, N) * N + floor((0:numel(u)-1)/N) + 1);
```

Comment: Your code as it stands gives me an error. Do you mean `u(mod(0:numel(u)-1, numel(u)/N)*N + floor((0:numel(u)-1)/numel(u)*N) + 1)`?